# My PHP code is not running in lamp on my Ubuntu OS

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, lamp

I installed apache2, mysql-server and also phpmyadmin in lamp on my Ubuntu OS.

I used the codebase from a project I did on windows using Xampp that has been working very well. Now, i tried to use those same codes on the lamp server. I've sent the file to my /var/www/ folders.

Initially, it was downloading the file and showing me the codes when I ran it, instead of running normally on my browser. I've tried using Google with many options but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: This is a bit vague - but the Apache default docroot is `/var/www/html/` rather than just `/var/www/`

Comment: pls share your apache2.conf file

Comment: Let me also change the Apache docroot to /var/www/html rather than the /var/www/ that i used initially.

Answer (score 0):

When the webserver send you the PHP code means that you didn't configure the apache to parse it by mod_php.

Please follows a guide to configure PHP with apache [here the one from DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-install-php) .

Start your reading from **Step3**

Comment: Okay Ivan, let me try that out. I'll let you know. Thank you for your response.